# Font rendering issue on iOS mobile devices

Tags: ios, css, text-formatting

I have one problem what find only on iOS and don't know to solve.

[image]

On image above you can see checkmark list where is complete font bad rendered and pixelate. I don't know why and how to solve this. I try various things from transform and text-rendering options to shaddow tricks.

I realy need help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be working fine on my iPhone 4S and iPad Air 2

Comment: This is iPhone 6. Generaly, I can't generate this problem, I get this image from my boss and he have that problem on his phone. That mean will happen on other phones but don't know where and why. One my friend try on iPhone 6 Plus and not see this issue.

Comment: Did u have any lucky solving this issue?

Comment: Hi @ThiagoUruray try with this: `box-shadow: #529e06 0 0 1px, #529e06 0 0 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #529e06 0 0 1px, #529e06 0 0 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #529e06 0 0 1px, #529e06 0 0 2px;
    -ms-box-shadow: #529e06 0 0 1px, #529e06 0 0 2px;
    -o-box-shadow: #529e06 0 0 1px, #529e06 0 0 2px;`

Answer (score 1):

I think `-webkit-font-smoothing` is the culprit here; `-webkit-font-smoothing:none` looks pretty bad on my iPhone 6s.

Christoph Zillgens has a really good [test page for -webkit-font-smoothing](http://files.christophzillgens.com/webkit-font-smoothing.html) which shows this clearly.